# Bootstrap Grid unevenly arranged in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am building a website using Bootstrap. I have used `Grid`.
The grids are evenly arranged in **Google Chrome** But are unevenly arranged when viewed in **Mozilla Firefox** and **Microsoft Edge**.
The basic structure is as follows:

```
<row>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
</row>
<row>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
</row>
.
.
</row> //n-th row
```

You can view the website for the output:
[**Link to Website**](http://flixbuz.com/)

Comment: You need to put 12 `<div>`'s in one row. Try it. Or at least 6. Only 6 and 12 are divisble into: 2x3 or 4x3, 1x6 or 2x6.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No, it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add   `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

**before every `<row>` tag is closed...like below**

```
    <row>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    <row>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopadding"><div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    .
    .
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row> //n-th row
```

Comment: In my opinin, this is a workaround... but it's working!